# Unable to capture exception message when using PowerShell script in Groovy script for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a Groovy script that runs a Jenkins pipeline and includes a PowerShell script. However, when an exception is thrown by the PowerShell script, I'm unable to print the exception message in the catch block. Here's my code:

```
def call() {
    node {
        timestamps {
            ansiColor('xterm') {
                try {
                    powershell """
                        throw new Exception("ERROR: This is a test Exception.")
                    """
                } catch (error) {
                    println("Caught error: ${error.getMessage()}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using error.message, error.printStackTrace(), and error.cause.getMessage(), but none of them print the error message. Instead, I receive the message "script returned exit code 1".

Can anyone help me capture the error message properly?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you cannot pass exception from powershell to groovy, in the same way as you cannot pass variables between them.

Best course of action there would be to catch exception within your powershell script, write to the output, exit without error and then parse output for this error.

Something like this:

```
try {
  def output = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: """
    Write-Output "Some output before error"
    try {
        throw "test error"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "MyPersonalError:" \$PSItem.ToString()
        exit 0
    }
  """)
  echo output // to show output of script otherwise suppressed by `returnStdout: true`
  // if you want intime show of output with `returnStdout: true` you might use tee and subsequent read output from file

  // check if error wraped with our catch happen
  def matcher = output =~ /MyPersonalError:\s+([\s\S]+)/
  // if yes - print it
  if(matcher.size() == 1){
    echo matcher[0][1]
  }
  else {
      echo "no errors"
  }
}  catch (e) {
    echo "Something out of ordinary happen. Shouldn't ever be. $e"
}
```